# Draw javascript lines with a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, graph

I have drawn a simple graph with javascript and displayed it on a html canvas with the code below,

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>

var dat = new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,300-dat[0]);
ctx.lineTo(50,300-dat[1]);
ctx.lineTo(100,300-dat[2]);
ctx.lineTo(150,300-dat[3]);
ctx.lineTo(200,300-dat[4]);
ctx.lineTo(250,300-dat[5]);
ctx.lineTo(300,300-dat[6]);
ctx.lineTo(350,300-dat[7]);
ctx.lineTo(400,300-dat[8]);
ctx.stroke();

</script>
<html>
```

In this code each line gets drawn by using the data from the array named dat. But how can i create a loop that will draw the lines instead of drawing each line separately without a loop as in the code?

I tried the for loop below but with no success,

```
<script>
var dat = new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
//ctx.moveTo(0,250);
ctx.moveTo(0,300-dat[0]);
var j = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    j = j + 50;
    ctx.lineTo(j,300-dat[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
```

Is there any other ways?

Comment: `int i` ?? you probably mean `var i`..

Comment: It should work. Can you create a fiddle to reproduce the problem?(also, you don't need to keep the `j` variable, just `ctx.lineTo(i*50,300-dat[i])` would do) Edit: GitaarLab is right, `var i` instead of `int i` in the for loop

Comment: It does http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mxZ2L/

Comment: Next time look in the [JavaScript console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to see error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `int` declaration in javascript. If you replace that with the proper `var` then your function works:

```
var dat = new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
//ctx.moveTo(0,250);
ctx.moveTo(0,300-dat[0]);
var j = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    j = j + 50;
    ctx.lineTo(j,300-dat[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VbDG9/).

From here on you could improve the code by not hardcoding the `dat` array `length` and caching it:

```
var dat = new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256)
,     c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
,   ctx = c.getContext("2d")
; //end local var

ctx.moveTo(0,300-dat[0]);
for(var i = 1, j = 0, L=dat.length; i < L; i++){
    j += 50;
    ctx.lineTo(j,300-dat[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/338e2/)

Answer (score 1):

in javascript you should use `var` not `int`.
and you can simplify your code:

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/DXmn9/2/)**

```
var dat = new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");zz

for(var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++){
    ctx.lineTo(i*50,300-dat[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: I liked your answer so I fooled with slight simplification - replacing the for loop with:  `dat.forEach( function(el, idx) { ctx.lineTo(idx * 50, 300-el); } );
ctx.stroke();`